# Refresh tokens on multiple devices

Tags: refresh-token

I have an Api and a mobile client. I am using refresh tokens as following:

1. User provides credentials, Api returns back an access token and a refresh token. The refresh token is then saved with its expiration dateTime in users table in the DB.
2. Client consumes some protected resources using the given access token.
3. Access token expires, so the client provides his refresh token and gets new pair of tokens.
4. Step 2 and 3 repeats over and over.

Problem:
Let's say user has 2 devices, A and B. He successfully logged in using device A, so he got 2 tokens and he is happy. As soon as the user logs in from device B, the Api will send him new pair of tokens, which mean the new refresh token will override the already given one to device A. Now user goes back to device A aaaand it's gone (invalid refresh token!) so he has to provide credentials again, which I, the user and you don't want to.

Suggestions:
I have found 2 approaches to solve the problem, but because I am pretty new to this topic I can't see which is best practice:

Approach A:
Save multiple refresh tokens per user, and saving a device identifier (still no idea what exactly in case of different client types like mobile, browser and desktop client!) but anyway. In this approach when a user logs in from device A, the Api provides both tokens. User logs in from device B, the Api delivers new pair of tokens. He goes back to device A, he uses his first token again (still valid).

Approach B:
Keep 1 refresh token per user. when user logs in from device B, Api sends back the only refresh token (I should not care about the devices as long as the user provides valid credentials, right?)

Could you point out the pros and cons for each approach?

Comment: "I should not care about the devices as long as the user provides valid credentials, right" Keeping track of device ids isn't necessary for approach A or B, so I am not sure how you would use these ids. (You just need to compare the refresh token in the request with the refresh token in the database.)

Comment: Did you mean what to save in the token? You can save the `user_id` in the refresh and access jwt tokens, and use that id to search the database and obtain `user.refreshTokens`. However, you could also use the `device_id` to search for the corresponding user, but what if there are multiple users on the same device?

Answer (score 16):

Approach A is the normal way to handle this. Access/refresh tokens should *not* be shared accross different sessions/devices.

Each should get their own pair. When you use the `refresh_token` operation, it should only expire the refresh token that was used with that request, and not any unrelated ones.

Comment: What kind of device identifier should i keep then? Especially if I have multiple clients of different types?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with device identifier, or what that means in the context of this question.

Comment: If I want to keep several refresh tokens and each for a unique device, how should I identify each device?

Comment: Doesn't the token identify the device? Only the device knows the token assigned to it

Comment: I see. I got confused because of the terminologies, my bad. So basically I just need to create 1:n between user and refresh tokens. And it doesn't matter from how many devices the user logs in. As long as he provides valid credentials, I will issue him new token and keep it in the DB on my server. In this case if he is not using a particlar device any more, the refresh token generated and sent to him on that device will stay in DB unless he logs out from all devices (deleting all refresh tokens for this user).

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. I would also recommend reading the OAuth2 and OAuth2.1 documentation again, if you haven't in a while.

Comment: I will. Just one last thing, if I have multiple refresh tokens per user, and a user posts a lot of logins with valid credentials on many different devices, I will have many tokens saved in the DB. Now if the user performs log out, i will delete that one token. If he wants global log out I will delete all refresh tokens for this user. What if he logs in on so many devices and never logs out? the tokens will eventually expire but they are just hanging there in the DB! should I have a worker that runs let's say once a day to clear all expired tokens from DB?

Comment: Sure, cleaning up expired tokens from time to time seems reasonable.

Comment: @Karro for cleanup what you can do is store the refresh-tokens in a separate table with the expiry date.
Run a cron job weekly and delete all records from that table whose exipry date is over

Comment: Better yet, I would clean up expired refresh tokens when the user performs log out or log out everywhere. This way you won't need another cron job.

Comment: @RelaxedCoder in my experience most users don't log out though! So it's more likely for a refresh token to time out, than a user explicitly using a logout feature.

Comment: I agree that most users are not logging out but they do log in. Clean up expired refresh tokens when a new refresh token is generated during the login process.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this recently with the following approach:

Each user database entry has a `refreshTokens` field, which is a `RefreshTokenObject` array with the following format: `{token: <tokenUUID>, creationDate: Date}`

**Sign in**

Each time a user signs in, a new `RefreshTokenObject` is concatted to the existing token object list.

**Token Refresh**

Backend performs a `map` on the `RefreshTokenObjects` entry, replacing the found `RefreshTokenObject` with a new token and creation date, sending the new refresh + access token to the user. If the token is not found, server returns 401 with `refresh token expired` in the body, prompting the frontend to re-sign in.

**Sign Out**

Frontend will post to `/api/login/signout` with body `{ userId: <id>, refreshToken: <tokenUUID> }` each time a sign out happens. The backend will then remove the corresponding token if found in the list. *Note:* I chose to not make the backend return 404 if the refreshToken was not found; this is an extremely odd case and will only result in a re-login at it's worst case.

**Good Practices**

Because many databases have a document size limit, you have to be careful with ever-growing arrays. I implemented a `clearOldTokens` function that runs each time login, logout, or refresh happens. It simply compares all existing tokens' `creationDate` field with the current time, and, if the token is expired, it will remove that token from the `refreshTokenObjects` array of the user.

It's even smarter to use Device ID and such to keep track of this; just more work.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question about multidevices and multi refreshtokens.

Comment: @VictorMartinezCalvo It does; if you read my previous post you would see that my method involves an array called `refreshTokens` which holds on array of refresh tokens for various devices.

Comment: @1Ghasthunter1 what if an attacker steals one of the refresh tokens and uses it while it's still valid to get a new refresh & access token? the legitimate user would be logged out (on the attacked device) and would have to re-login. but the attacker would keep his access, as he can get as many fresh access & refresh tokens as he wants.

Comment: @Patito well you'd have to log in and log out of all sessions (e.g. hit a button that clears all of the refresh and access tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the access token lasts 5 minutes and the refresh token lasts 1 week. Once the access token expires, you check if the database has the refresh token that was included in the request. (You can also cleanup expired refresh tokens.)

If everything goes well, I generate new access **and** refresh tokens to reset the expiry date of the refresh token to next week (so the user doesn't have to login again unless he wasn't active for a long time). That means the previous refresh token is no longer valid/used and needs to be deleted.

Only the device making the request will know about the new refresh token and it would be difficult to communicate this change to other devices, so **approach B won't work**. (I doubt you can send notifications to change the cookies (containing the refresh token) of other devices.)

---

Also, if the same refresh token is used by 2 devices, this might mean that the second device is an attacker that got access to your refresh token. This can be detected and you can invalidate all refresh tokens [code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/refresh-tokens/blob/main/api/src/middlewares/isAuthenticated.js#L26).

If the attacker got access to your refresh token, they will need to generate an access token, so you can perform some checks. The way I did it is that if the user doesn't have the request token (because it was deleted when creating a new one), that means the token is being reused `if (!user.refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken))`.

1. User A is logged in
2. Attacker B steals token
3. User A generates new access and refresh tokens
4. Attacker B doesn't pass the `if (!user.refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken))` since user A deleted the refresh token when refreshing the access token
5. User A needs to re-enter credentials after access token expires since all refresh tokens were deleted

However:

1. User A is logged in
2. Attacker B steals token
3. Attacker B passes the check (before the access token of User A expires)
4. User A needs to be active and make a request so that the check doesn't pass and the refresh tokens are deleted. I am not sure how to make it so the attacker doesn't pass the check. (But at least the user is still probably active after 5 minutes)
5. Attacker B will have 5 minutes with the access token generated to do some damage, but I don't know if it's easy to steal refresh tokens and use them within a short time window

Edit:

When the same user has multiple tabs, they will have the same refresh token (in cookies) but different access tokens (in memory and added in HTTP headers). I thought that the server will think that the second tab is a second device/attacker. However, it should still work. When the second tab changes the refresh token, the first tab will also use the new refresh token in its requests.

Also, if the user sends 2 requests one after another rapidly and the access token expired, the first request will delete the refresh token and the second request will trigger the `if (!user.refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken))` check. However, the second request has an access token (as apposed to Attacker B), so you could call a different method (or keep old tokens but mark them as invalid).

Comment: this sounds good for a one-device login. But how would this work if the user is logged in in multiple devices simultaneously? Then you would need to store multiple refresh tokens in the DB. If one gets compromised, how to detect that? Probably by invalidating all refresh tokens if an invalid one gets used, effectively logging the user out on all devices?

Comment: @Patito Each device needs its own tokens. `user.refreshTokens` is an array of strings. You can detect if 2 devices (second being the attacker) are using the same token by whether it is still present in `user.refreshTokens` or was already deleted by the first device. In the second scenario (after "However:"), one of the refresh tokens belongs to the attacker. I am not sure how you would keep track of which one it is, so it's probably better to delete all `user.refreshTokens`. This will force the user to reenter their password (which the attacker doesn't know) on each device.