# How to manage multi-device simultaneous login with JWT tokens?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, nestjs, passport-jwt

My query is regarding supporting multi-device login for the same user at the same time using JWT tokens. I am using NestJS as my backend.

User table: userid, username, password(contains hashed password), name, refreshToken(contains hashed refresh token)

When the user does a /api/login call, on having a valid username and password, the access token and refresh token are generated using jwt passport library. The refresh token is hashed and stored in the refresh column of the user table for that particular user and the access token and the refresh token are sent to the client through the response.

During the /api/refresh call, the refresh token sent by the user is validated with the hashed refresh token that is present in the user table for that user and then, a new access token and a new refresh token are generated. The new refresh token is hashed and updated in the user table refreshToken column for that same user row.

This flow works perfectly for a user logged in with a single device. When the same user gets logged in using multiple devices at the same time, during login, the refresh token is updated in the refreshToken column of the user table for the same user row, which makes us lose an existing/valid refresh token for the same user.

Flow:

1. user 1 logs in using device 1 --> refreshToken column for user 1 is updated with a new refresh token
2. user 1 logs in using device 2 --> refreshToken column for user 1 is overwritten with a new refresh token and we lose the refresh token that was created for device 1

I would like to know what would be the best industrial practice to manage the JWT refresh flow for a user logged in with multiple devices at the same time?

Comment: Having only refresh token won't work, you will need one refresh token per browser/device. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77675270/20898396) As a bonus, if a second device (attacker that stole your token somehow) uses the same refresh token, you can detect that and delete all refresh tokens and force the user to re-enter credentials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way would be to keep the refresh tokens in a separate table. Usually, refresh tokens are kept separately from the user's account data, as the user can have more refresh tokens active at any given time. Whenever a refresh token is used you can find the concrete token and create a new one in its place.

By the way, there is no need to hash the refresh tokens kept in your database. They are unique to your system, they're not passwords.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I think this will work. But, there is a minor issue that I see here. The reason behind hashing the token in the DB is to prevent people with access to the DB from being able to use the token to access someone else's account. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @KunalKarmakar if someone already has access to the database then can't they already access any user's account data? Unless you are storing the refresh tokens in a completely seperate database.

Comment: @BigGerman makes sense. Still, just for a bit of security.

Comment: it's to prevent an internal employee from being being able to super easily impersonate a user. Of course, any employee who is viewing database info can see everything, but they still can't usually behave like a real user. They would have to edit the database in very particular ways and touch systems that may be spread out all over the place running live. With the hash, you remove that edgecase

Comment: if you hash the RT, you cant decrypt it to know if this RT is linked to the AccessToken. In case of multiple device, thus multiple entry in DB for the same user_id. Usually many example only compare the RT from client and the Hash RT from DB. I was thinking this way, when user signIn, first create RT and insert into db, get the row id, and insert the id into AT creation. wdyt?