# How to manage refresh tokens when logging in from multiple devices

Tags: refresh-token

I use nestjs to manage `refreshToken`s.

I am storing userId in key and token in value.

The `refreshToken` is designed to change when a user logs in.

However, if user log in from another device, the user of the first browser will no longer be able to renew the `accessToken`.

If I use the same `refreshToken`, there is no way to notify other browsers when an update has occurred.

I allow logins on multiple devices. How to manage refresh tokens?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a one to many relationship with user and refresh tokens and store those refresh tokens (either as array or in a seprate table).
find your answers here. Hope it helps

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903200/refresh-tokens-on-multiple-devices)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511998/how-to-manage-multi-device-simultaneous-login-with-jwt-tokens)