# Refresh token rotation for different client but same user

Tags: oauth, access-token, refresh-token

For refresh token rotation and update both refresh token and access token way, I am wondering, for the same user, if he or she opens different browser and logs in. This means, for the same user, tokens rotation would think it is stolen. Am I right?

If I don't want this to happen, can I use IP combined with user ID to identity the user? Is it secure? I know if it is shared IP, then no.

Is there anything that hacker cannot fake which can distinguish hacker and the user? I think Phone has its device ID of some sort. How about browser?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing completely different concepts

- Oauth - authorization.
- Open id connect - sign-in - authentication.

Access tokens and refresh tokens are used for authorization.  A user grants your application access to their data.  The user does not have to be present for this to happen. There for using an access token to prove a users identity is not the correct course of action.

You should use open id connect, to authencation a user - sign them in.  Then you should get an id token back which contains claims, one of these claims is the subject claim which should be the users id on the system you are connecting to.   You should use that to identify the user.

## As for hacking oauth. (Authorization)

Access tokens are short lived they will give your application access to a system for a limited amount of time usually an hour.  If a hacker got the access token they would also have access to the system for this hour. access tokens are self contained. no further verification is preformed.

Refresh tokens require the client id and client secrete in order to request a new access token. So the hacker would need to have your client id, client secret, be on one of the valid redirect uris. in order to request a new access token.  This is why you should not set a redirect uri to localhost.

## Hacking and open id connect.(authencation)

Well as far as signin goes the hacker would need to have the users login and password in order to signin in and get an id token back. You should be good to assume that this is not a hacker and is the user behind the machine.

Comment: "client id and client secret". I think that's where my question is at core. What is that? It's not the app ID, right? In mobile app case, it's the device ID I suppose. In the browser web app case, I suppose IP address, to certain degree?

Comment: mobile apps have completely different flow.  Its all based upon a device id, package name or a SHA-1 signing certificate.

Comment: Hi to you after over a year. :) What is this "client id and client secret" in your answer? My idea is access token 1 hour, refresh token 1 week. refresh token is basically used to refresh access token. the data in transit is access token so it could be stolen. refresh token is unlikely. So if user is not logged in for 1 week, refresh token expired, then user needs to log in again. There is no client id or secret involved in my understanding.

Comment: Refresh tokens only expire after a week if your App is in testing switch it to production and it won't expire.  Refresh tokens have nothing to do with login

Answer (score 0):

Each browser and device will have different refresh and access tokens, so token reuse detection won't be triggered. If the same browser has multiple tabs, then if one tab changes the refresh token in cookies, the other tabs will also start using the new refresh token.

I just store the user id in the token to be able to find the user by id and check the field `refreshTokens: [String]`. [code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/refresh-tokens/blob/main/api/src/utils/tokens.js#L26)

```
createAccessToken(id) {
    return jwt.sign(
      {
        id,
      },
      ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: access_token_expires_in }
    )
  },
  createRefreshToken(id) {
    return jwt.sign(
      {
        id,
      },
      REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: refresh_token_expires_in }
    )
  }
```

[related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77675270/20898396)